# Embeded html forms with photos using thunderbird

Tags: html, forms, html-email, thunderbird

i am trying to embed the following html form in email, using Thunderbird.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>eisitirio</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (eisitirio.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="835" height="4724" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="eisitirio_01.png" width="835" height="1338" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <a href="https://www.ticketservices.gr/event/goutou-goupatou-theatro-aneton/?fbclid=IwAR0Gy0HRV9hRApR7jZajDtZ9Bt4Xa7FliSTHbDR7M1-kOO8kHgMdIvveLNw" target="_blank">
                <img src="tickets.png" width="835" height="245" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="eisitirio_03.png" width="835" height="1231" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03upwfqlKEo" target="_blank">
                <img src="teaser.png" width="835" height="305" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="eisitirio_05.png" width="835" height="1325" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/endynameiensemble" target="_blank">
                <img src="facebook.png" width="243" height="280" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4ecFndGyTEbycrUpnEkqUw" target="_blank">
                <img src="youtube.png" width="186" height="280" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/endynamei.ensemble/" target="_blank">
                <img src="instagram.png" width="174" height="280" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.endynamei.com/menoy" target="_blank">
                <img src="site.png" width="232" height="280" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

I try to insert the html code by choosing insert->HTML in thunderbird
I can not make it work properly . Can somebody help me please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "it does not work properly"? It doesn't do anything - is there an error message? It doesn't quite look right -- in what way? You can paste screenshots here (best: expected & actual)

Comment: I mean that nothing shows up only empty tables

Comment: You need to host the images & link it back to the HTML before sending.

Comment: Where can I host them ;

Comment: Just google for image hosting, or get some generic/basic webhosting. By the way, this is not a 'form', and forms generally don't work on email - you might like to edit your title.